# python module i installed with pip shows up on pip list, but i cant import it into code?

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-module

others have asked this question but the answers are either too hard for me to understand or dont help.
i tried using many variations of python3 and python, pip3 and pip, sudo etc. they all said the package was already present. pip list command shows that numpy v1.23.1 is installed.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that didn't work either.
for context I'm tryna install numpy, python version:3.10.5

Comment: Is there any error while running command `python -c 'import numpy;'`?

Comment: nothing happens when i run " python -c 'import numpy;' "

Comment: No error means `python` in system's PATH has `numpy` installed. Where are you getting the error mentioned in question? IDE? Notebook? Which python interpreter are you using with this IDE/Notebook?

Comment: im not getting any errors, i try to to do import numpy as np but numpy has a squigly line underneath and typing np. doesnt show any recomendations, also np. and commands dont work.

Comment: Import warnings and failure to auto-complete, can be IDE issues. You've still not made clear how are you running the python code and exactly what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your Python and your pip module do not belong to the same environment/installation.

To make sure you install a module under the Python installation you want to use, run this at a command prompt:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: i did that and it said '
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.23.1)'

Comment: Make sure that you start the Python executable with the same command you use to install